# Fail to deploy WAR in Jenkins

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins for the first time and I wanna try it in local before deploy in my company.

So I have a `app.war` generated from eclipse : it's a maven project.
I wanna to build it in Jenkins and then deploy it in Tomcat 6.

So I set the "right" configuration I think in Jenkins, but when I have launch the build, I got a successful build in my project but it's not deploying in tomcat .

I'll put my console Output of Jenkins and the configuration

**Console Output Jenkins :**

[image]

**Configuration Jenkins**

[image]

So what's wrong with that ? Thnx

Answer (score 3):

**Solution to your question -Edited**

1. You have to select the appropriate container to deploy, from your question it is clear that you should choose Tomcat 7.X as a container.
2. Please use **Jenkins Deploy Plugin** which is configured with the following options as seen in the below [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277223/jenkins-auto-deploy-tomcat-7?rq=1). Also this link will be your solution.
3. Also you can embed the Tomcat Maven Plugin in your pom.xml like below

> ```
>  <plugin> 
>     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
>    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>     <version>2.2</version> 
>         <configuration>
>       <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
>       <server>TomcatServer</server>
>         <path>/YourPath</path>
>   </configuration> 
> </plugin>
> ```

4. Give the goals as clean install tomcat7:deploy -e

Comment: Thanx for your answer @Kumar , i use Tomcat6 i edited the post, i also tomcat7 but for an another application, and i got the deploy Plugin that's why i can choose `Deploy war/ear to a container` in the `Step post-build` and i also see the link it didn't resolve my problem